# False detection Opencv

Tags: opencv

I am working on vehicle detection. The program is working fine and detecting almost all the car. But there's is one problem, if the two cars are approaching together very closely than the detector is treating both the car as single car.

Comment: Please, describe how an object is detected in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Some non-maxima suppression mechanism is used in this kind of cases:

1. Compute all the candidate detections (red boxes); you should get 3 detections with the two cars on the right hand side.
2. Rank them according to some metric that tells you how good a detection is (some kind of ratio between headlamps size and distance?).
3. Among those candidate detections that are not consistent (those red boxes that overlap), suppress those with lower rank.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you detect a car, how about motor with one light only?

you are detecting from one picture or you could have video sequences?

one simple trick is, whenever you find a car, try to find single light dot "close/parallel" to them. If you find both sides, refine your car numbers.

there are other patterns could be use: like the little reflection on the ground. train your classifer with this would help.

and if you have video sequence, cars always shows "parallel" light dots rather than other cars/ motors.

Comment: Hi Flank and Chrono, thanks for replying. Could you please provide me some sort of example. My code is working fine, I applied even the subtraction method but at nighttime due to only availability of headlights this kinda situation is occuring. I am using image sequence. Thanks for your expert comments.

Answer (score 0):

Cross pairing is a common problem when multiple vehicles close to each other are in the scene.
You may use following step(s) to rectify this problem:
1. Use some tracking method (e.g. kalman filter), give some confidence score over the frames and and then confirm the car.
2. If the camera is calibrated then calculate the distance of each car from the host car, as you move away from the host car, distance between two blobs of the same car should decrease (perspective geometry).

Also, avoid giving very loose bounding box around the headlights as input to classifier.